# MULTIPLE LEFT JOINS AND ORDER BY

Tags: mysql, left-join, joomla1.5

I have following query on in my file:

```
function getItems($ShowFeatured,$OrderBy,$Order,$amountShow,$ShowPropertyID)

{        
switch($OrderBy) {
case 0 :
$OrderBy = 'p.id';
break;
case 1 :
$OrderBy = 'p.name';
break;
case 2 :
$OrderBy = 'p.price';
break;
case 3 :
$OrderBy = 'p.hits';
break;
case 4 :
$OrderBy = 'p.refresh_time';
break;
}
switch($Order) {
case 0 :
$Order = 'ASC';
break;
case 1 :
$Order = 'DESC';
break;
}   
if($ShowPropertyID){$where= 'WHERE p.id IN ('.$ShowPropertyID.')';}else{$where=        'WHERE p.published = 1 ';}
    if($ShowFeatured){$sqlFeatured= ' AND p.featured = 1';}
    $db = &JFactory::getDBO();     
    $query = 'SELECT p.*, i.name as imagename,c.id as key1,c.name as name_category,t.id as key5,t.name as name_type,cy.id as key2,cy.name as name_country,s.id as key3,s.name as name_state,l.id as key4,l.name as name_locality,'
            . ' CASE WHEN CHAR_LENGTH(p.alias) THEN CONCAT_WS(":", p.id, p.alias) ELSE p.id END as Pslug,'
    . ' CASE WHEN CHAR_LENGTH(c.alias) THEN CONCAT_WS(":", c.id, c.alias) ELSE c.id END as Cslug,'
    . ' CASE WHEN CHAR_LENGTH(cy.alias) THEN CONCAT_WS(":", cy.id, cy.alias) ELSE cy.id END as CYslug,'
    . ' CASE WHEN CHAR_LENGTH(s.alias) THEN CONCAT_WS(":", s.id, s.alias) ELSE s.id END as Sslug,'      
    . ' CASE WHEN CHAR_LENGTH(l.alias) THEN CONCAT_WS(":", l.id, l.alias) ELSE l.id END as Lslug, ' 
    . ' CASE WHEN CHAR_LENGTH(t.alias) THEN CONCAT_WS(":", t.id, t.alias) ELSE t.id END as Tslug '
            . ' FROM #__properties_products AS p '
            . ' LEFT JOIN #__properties_country AS cy ON cy.id = p.cyid '               
            . ' LEFT JOIN #__properties_state AS s ON s.id = p.sid '
            . ' LEFT JOIN #__properties_locality AS l ON l.id = p.lid '
            . ' LEFT JOIN #__properties_category AS c ON c.id = p.cid '
            . ' LEFT JOIN #__properties_type AS t ON t.id = p.type '
            . ' LEFT JOIN #__properties_images AS i ON  p.id = i.parent '
            . $where                
            . $sqlFeatured
            . ' GROUP BY p.id ' 
            . ' ORDER BY '.$OrderBy.' '.$Order
            . ' LIMIT '.$amountShow;

    $db->setQuery($query);  
    $items = $db->loadObjectList();



   // $items = ($items = $db->loadObjectList())?$items:array(); 
//echo str_replace('#_','jos',$query);


    return $items;
```

Part to get an image is following:

```
. ' LEFT JOIN #__properties_images AS i ON  p.id = i.parent '
```

This query orders images by i.parent - image that I get I don't like. In my database I have row i.ordering - is it possible to order images by i.ordering on above query?

Thanks.

Comment: That code seems to take a parameter for the order, none of which are for the i.parent column. Would be relatively easy to add an extra option to the SWITCH statement to order by i.ordering if you want.

Comment: No, the image is just one segment - if I put i.parent into swictch option it will just reorder results from database, but the picture is still the same. The problem is that I have multiple image table...

Comment: Ah, right. There are multiple images but you just want the latest / most important one returning. Think you would need a subselect of the images for that.

Comment: Currentlly I added to ' LEFT JOIN #__properties_images AS i ON  p.id = i.parent and i.ordering=1 ', but this is not the best idea, because i.ordering can also have negative values - idea to solve?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this for you query I think will do what you want.

```
$query = 'SELECT p.*, i.name as imagename,c.id as key1,c.name as name_category,t.id as key5,t.name as name_type,cy.id as key2,cy.name as name_country,s.id as key3,s.name as name_state,l.id as key4,l.name as name_locality,'
            . ' CASE WHEN CHAR_LENGTH(p.alias) THEN CONCAT_WS(":", p.id, p.alias) ELSE p.id END as Pslug,'
    . ' CASE WHEN CHAR_LENGTH(c.alias) THEN CONCAT_WS(":", c.id, c.alias) ELSE c.id END as Cslug,'
    . ' CASE WHEN CHAR_LENGTH(cy.alias) THEN CONCAT_WS(":", cy.id, cy.alias) ELSE cy.id END as CYslug,'
    . ' CASE WHEN CHAR_LENGTH(s.alias) THEN CONCAT_WS(":", s.id, s.alias) ELSE s.id END as Sslug,'      
    . ' CASE WHEN CHAR_LENGTH(l.alias) THEN CONCAT_WS(":", l.id, l.alias) ELSE l.id END as Lslug, ' 
    . ' CASE WHEN CHAR_LENGTH(t.alias) THEN CONCAT_WS(":", t.id, t.alias) ELSE t.id END as Tslug '
            . ' FROM #__properties_products AS p '
            . ' LEFT JOIN #__properties_country AS cy ON cy.id = p.cyid '               
            . ' LEFT JOIN #__properties_state AS s ON s.id = p.sid '
            . ' LEFT JOIN #__properties_locality AS l ON l.id = p.lid '
            . ' LEFT JOIN #__properties_category AS c ON c.id = p.cid '
            . ' LEFT JOIN #__properties_type AS t ON t.id = p.type '
            . ' LEFT JOIN (SELECT parent, MAX(ordering) AS MostImportant FROM #__properties_images GROUP BY parent) x ON  p.id = x.parent '
        . ' LEFT JOIN #__properties_images AS i ON  x.parent = i.parent AND x.MostImportant = i.ordering '
            . $where                
            . $sqlFeatured
            . ' GROUP BY p.id ' 
            . ' ORDER BY '.$OrderBy.' '.$Order
            . ' LIMIT '.$amountShow;
```

You might want to use MIN instead of MAX depending on which way the ordering works

Comment: Where? P.id is used on the join to get the required image in the same way as your original query, and x.parent id from that (which should be p.id) is used to join to get the actual image details